# Haskell complete text file indexer

Tags: java, haskell, recursion

Upon seeing a post earlier about text file indexing, i became curious as I'm currently learning to use Haskell (which isn't going well) as to if its possible to achieve the same goal easily in Haskell:
[How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

The objective of the class is to read a file, alphabetically order the words within the file and display the line numbers these words appear on.

Would the function in Haskell be able to be built in a similar approach to this?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function that will do the heavy-lifting you need:

```
import Data.List

sortWords :: String -> [(Int,String)]
sortWords contents = sortBy (\(_,w1) (_,w2) -> compare w1 w2) ys
  where xs = zip [1..] (lines contents)
        ys = concatMap (\(n,line) -> zip (repeat n) (words line)) xs
```

The only thing left to do is to write some simple IO code to read a file and nicely print results. If you run this function on the following input:

```
Here are some test
lines to see if this works...
What: about? punctuation!
```

You will get this:

```
(1,"Here")
(3,"What:")
(3,"about?")
(1,"are")
(2,"if")
(2,"lines")
(3,"punctuation!")
(2,"see")
(1,"some")
(1,"test")
(2,"this")
(2,"to")
(2,"works...")
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Haskell solution

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

numberWordsSorted :: String -> [(String,Int)]
numberWordsSorted  = sortBy (compare `on` fst)
                   . concat 
                   . zipWith (\n xs -> [(x,n)|x<- xs]) [1..]   -- add line numbers
                   . map words
                   . lines

main = fmap numberWordsSorted (readFile "example.txt") >>= mapM_ print
```

If you run it on `example.txt` with contents

```
the quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy dog
```

you get

```
("brown",1)
("dog",2)
("fox",1)
("jumps",2)
("lazy",2)
("over",2)
("quick",1)
("the",1)
("the",2)
```

You should use `Data.Map` instead of pairs if you're rather see `the [1,2]` instead of two lines of output.

Comment: thats great. but i am also getting lots of other details of the file in my output. such as the font and document sizes. could that be because the file is '.rtf'?

Comment: @dizzytri99er It's definitely because it's rtf - open it in notepad to see the data. You could open it in a word processor and save it as text to ger rid of the formatting (easy, quick), or find an rtf library to parse it.

Comment: yeah you were right. only gotta remove the stop words now(such as 'and') :(